# GCP public file download without prefix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

When I visit a public URL to my uploaded file, the filename includes the prefix, resulting in a super long filename.

Is there a way to download a file from the browser without including the prefix?

Maybe a setting or metadata to the uploaded file, or something?

My backend runs on NodeJS, if that's relevant.

Comment: To what do you refer as "prefix"?

Comment: @YeriPelona have you read the GCP Storage Bucket API? A prefix is kind of like a path-like string, example: `/myfolder/myfile.txt` where `/myfolder/` is the prefix

Comment: What's the problem to have a super long name?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it's not optimal for my users and I've received complaints

Comment: Just to be sure, what is too long? The URL to download the file? Or the file name when saved on the workstation?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere as per my question `the filename includes the prefix, resulting in a super long filename`

Answer (score 0):

In your webserver, you can override the default file name by writing a specific header

```
request.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'filename="fileName.txt"');
```

Comment: this is not GCP Storage related. I said in my question the following: `When I visit a public URL to my uploaded file`

Comment: It's not GCS related, it's HTTP related!

Comment: That's what I'm saying. I need a solution to my GCP problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your GCP problem... Can you show how the file are downloaded? From your backend or directly on GCS?